# search for value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am modifying an old question, not sure if this is the right way.

This is the code I have

```
Array ( [0] => Gymnasium [1] => Mini market [2] => Jogging track )
```

What I need to do is search inside the above array for specific value and then check the checkbox accordingly.

I tried this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="facilities1" value="Swimming pool" name="et_er_facilities[]" <?php if (in_array('Swimming pool', $et_er_facilities)) {?>checked="checked"<?php }?>>
<input type="checkbox" id="facilities2" value="Gymnasium" name="et_er_facilities[]" <?php if (in_array('Gymnasium', $et_er_facilities)) {?>checked="checked"<?php }?>>
```

So the idea is to mark the checkbox if the value is present in the above array and that array is going to have more values instead of those 3 I listed as sample.

The problem I am having is it only marks the checkbox if it matches the first value. ie;

> if array has Gymnasium value in it and its on first index, it will
>   mark it. However if the 2nd indexed value is also matching but it
>   won't mark any of them after the first one.

Please help.

thanks

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried the common solutions people do, but that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Makes sure existing files and directories are not rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrites /video/2394943asdfsd0323 to /video/?key=2394943asdfsd0323
RewriteRule ^video/(.+)$ video/?key=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it just redirects me to the site homepage. Kindly advise what could be the issue?

Comment: Try to change the `[L]` flag to `[R]` and see if the pattern matches + where you are reritten. Are you sure `.htaccess` files are supported on your server? If you try to write any bogus directives in the `.htaccess` file does the server return an internal server error (as intended)?

Comment: tried [R] also, no luck. yes htaccess supported as I said I am on wordpress. wp rewrites are working well on it.

Comment: The rule must be placed above the last WP rule which rewrites to *index.php*